# What format should data be in for a Dangle JS graph?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I am using dangle.js, a visualization tool built for Angular JS based on D3. I am trying to output a graph by calling the directive with the html

```
<fs-area bind="data" on-click="filterByDate" />
```

In my controller I have the code

```
$scope.data = [
{x: 1, y: 100},
{x: 2, y: 20},
{x: 3, y: 43}
];
```

However, the graph is not showing, probably because I'm not sure how the directive expects the data to be given. I'm new to D3, can anyone point me in the right direction or give me an example dataset that would display in the graph? Thanks. Dangle.js docs aren't very helpful http://www.fullscale.co/dangle/

Comment: Do you get an error message or anything like that?

Comment: No error message in console, the graph simply doesn't appear. I'm sure the js is working because it displays the x and y axes for the area graph, but with no data. I'm thinking of just sticking with flat D3.js even though there seems to be quite a learning curve for using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fs-area` expects data to be present in a [sub-field `entries`](https://github.com/fullscale/dangle/blob/master/src/modules/area/area.js#L155) and the `x` and `y` accessors to be `time` and `count` respectively. Hence, this should work:

```
$scope.data = {
    entries: [
      {time: 1, count: 100},
      {time: 2, count: 20},
      {time: 3, count: 43}
    ]
};
```

Comment: Thank! I have a graph appearing now! I see where to look now to find the info for the other ones. Thank you.

Comment: @AndyHadjigeorgiou If this solved your problem, consider marking it as an answer.